# Contour plot on 2 parameter data in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I have a numpy object with shape (1000,3) that I wish do a contour plot of. The first two columns represent x and y values and the 3rd is the associated density value at the the point denoted by the x and y values. These are NOT evenly spaced as the x and y values were generated by MCMC sampling methods. I wish to plot the x and y values and demarcate points which have density at a certain level.

I have tried calling the contour function but it does not appear to work.

presuming I have a data object such that np.shape(data) gives (1000,3)

```
plt.figure()
contour(data[:,0],data[:,1],data[:,2])
plt.show()
```

this does not seem to work and gives the following error

```
TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array
```

I understand z, the 3rd column needs to be some sort of meshgrid, but the all the examples I have seen seen to rely on constructing one from evenly spaced x and y which I do not have. Help appreciated on how I can resolve this.

EDIT: I have figured it out. Need to use the method for unevenly spaced points as described here.

https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/griddata_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-griddata-demo-py

Comment: I have figured it out. Need to use the griddata method that works for unevenly spaced points as described here.

https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/griddata_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-griddata-demo-py

Comment: You could also try pylabs contour function. It should allow your current data format

Comment: Doesn't pylab use the same contour function as matplotlib though? would appreciate an example code snippet or a link if you can.

Comment: Forget what I said, I just realized that was wrong.
I think your solution looks fine. Other than that, I think this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897544/make-a-contour-plot-by-using-three-1d-arrays-in-python also does the job.