# How to convert a 3D plot into a 2D filled contour

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, contourf

I have a 3D plot that looks quite nice, and I'd like to convert this to a 2D filled contour plot, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. Here is my setup

```py
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

x=np.array([0.3, 0.304, 0.3, 0.3, 0.304, 0.308, 0.308, 0.3, 0.304, 0.312, 0.308, 0.3, 0.312, 0.304, 0.316, 0.304, 0.312, 0.3, 0.308, 0.32, 0.316, 0.32, 0.3, 0.308, 0.304, 0.312, 0.316, 0.324, 0.304, 0.312, 0.316, 0.3, 0.328, 0.324, 0.308, 0.32, 0.33199999999999996, 0.3, 0.304, 0.324, 0.32, 0.328, 0.308, 0.316, 0.312, 0.304, 0.3, 0.33199999999999996, 0.33599999999999997, 0.32, 0.324, 0.328, 0.312, 0.308, 0.316, 0.304, 0.33199999999999996, 0.33999999999999997, 0.308, 0.33599999999999997, 0.3, 0.32, 0.328, 0.316, 0.312, 0.324, 0.312, 0.308, 0.33999999999999997, 0.33199999999999996, 0.3, 0.304, 0.344, 0.33599999999999997, 0.32, 0.324, 0.316, 0.328, 0.316, 0.33599999999999997, 0.308, 0.304, 0.33999999999999997, 0.3, 0.312, 0.33199999999999996, 0.344, 0.348, 0.32, 0.328, 0.324, 0.3, 0.316, 0.308, 0.33199999999999996, 0.312, 0.33599999999999997, 0.348, 0.344, 0.32, 0.304, 0.33999999999999997, 0.352, 0.328, 0.324, 0.32, 0.348, 0.33199999999999996, 0.352, 0.324, 0.33599999999999997, 0.304, 0.33999999999999997, 0.356, 0.312, 0.308, 0.316, 0.344, 0.3, 0.328, 0.344, 0.328, 0.308, 0.33199999999999996, 0.312, 0.33999999999999997, 0.316, 0.32, 0.324, 0.356, 0.304, 0.33599999999999997, 0.3, 0.36, 0.352, 0.348, 0.344, 0.304, 0.316, 0.348, 0.324, 0.33599999999999997, 0.32, 0.33199999999999996, 0.328, 0.352, 0.33999999999999997, 0.356, 0.312, 0.36, 0.308, 0.308, 0.328, 0.352, 0.33999999999999997, 0.348, 0.33199999999999996, 0.32, 0.36, 0.312, 0.344, 0.33599999999999997, 0.316, 0.324, 0.356, 0.33199999999999996, 0.348, 0.36, 0.33999999999999997, 0.324, 0.316, 0.328, 0.32, 0.312, 0.33599999999999997, 0.344, 0.356, 0.352, 0.33599999999999997, 0.33199999999999996, 0.36, 0.316, 0.32, 0.33999999999999997, 0.344, 0.356, 0.352, 0.328, 0.324, 0.348, 0.33599999999999997, 0.33199999999999996, 0.33999999999999997, 0.344, 0.324, 0.348, 0.352, 0.32, 0.356, 0.36, 0.328, 0.344, 0.33999999999999997, 0.33599999999999997, 0.33199999999999996, 0.324, 0.328, 0.352, 0.36, 0.348, 0.356, 0.344, 0.33599999999999997, 0.33999999999999997, 0.33199999999999996, 0.348, 0.352, 0.36, 0.356, 0.328, 0.33999999999999997, 0.33199999999999996, 0.352, 0.33599999999999997, 0.344, 0.348, 0.36, 0.356, 0.352, 0.348, 0.33999999999999997, 0.33599999999999997, 0.356, 0.344, 0.36, 0.33999999999999997, 0.344, 0.348, 0.36, 0.356, 0.352, 0.352, 0.344, 0.348, 0.356, 0.36, 0.36, 0.352, 0.356, 0.348, 0.352, 0.36, 0.356, 0.356, 0.36, 0.36])

y=np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.004, 0.008, 0.004, 0.0, 0.004, 0.012, 0.008, 0.0, 0.008, 0.016, 0.004, 0.012, 0.0, 0.016, 0.008, 0.02, 0.012, 0.0, 0.004, 0.004, 0.024, 0.016, 0.02, 0.012, 0.008, 0.0, 0.024, 0.016, 0.012, 0.028, 0.0, 0.004, 0.02, 0.008, 0.0, 0.032, 0.028, 0.008, 0.012, 0.004, 0.024, 0.016, 0.02, 0.032, 0.036000000000000004, 0.004, 0.0, 0.016, 0.012, 0.008, 0.024, 0.028, 0.02, 0.036000000000000004, 0.008, 0.0, 0.032, 0.004, 0.04, 0.02, 0.012, 0.024, 0.028, 0.016, 0.032, 0.036000000000000004, 0.004, 0.012, 0.044, 0.04, 0.0, 0.008, 0.024, 0.02, 0.028, 0.016, 0.032, 0.012, 0.04, 0.044, 0.008, 0.048, 0.036000000000000004, 0.016, 0.004, 0.0, 0.028, 0.02, 0.024, 0.052000000000000005, 0.036000000000000004, 0.044, 0.02, 0.04, 0.016, 0.004, 0.008, 0.032, 0.048, 0.012, 0.0, 0.024, 0.028, 0.036000000000000004, 0.008, 0.024, 0.004, 0.032, 0.02, 0.052000000000000005, 0.016, 0.0, 0.044, 0.048, 0.04, 0.012, 0.056, 0.028, 0.016, 0.032, 0.052000000000000005, 0.028, 0.048, 0.02, 0.044, 0.04, 0.036000000000000004, 0.004, 0.056, 0.024, 0.06, 0.0, 0.008, 0.012, 0.02, 0.06, 0.048, 0.016, 0.04, 0.028, 0.044, 0.032, 0.036000000000000004, 0.012, 0.024, 0.008, 0.052000000000000005, 0.004, 0.056, 0.06, 0.04, 0.016, 0.028, 0.02, 0.036000000000000004, 0.048, 0.008, 0.056, 0.024, 0.032, 0.052000000000000005, 0.044, 0.012, 0.04, 0.024, 0.012, 0.032, 0.048, 0.056, 0.044, 0.052000000000000005, 0.06, 0.036000000000000004, 0.028, 0.016, 0.02, 0.04, 0.044, 0.016, 0.06, 0.056, 0.036000000000000004, 0.032, 0.02, 0.024, 0.048, 0.052000000000000005, 0.028, 0.044, 0.048, 0.04, 0.036000000000000004, 0.056, 0.032, 0.028, 0.06, 0.024, 0.02, 0.052000000000000005, 0.04, 0.044, 0.048, 0.052000000000000005, 0.06, 0.056, 0.032, 0.024, 0.036000000000000004, 0.028, 0.044, 0.052000000000000005, 0.048, 0.056, 0.04, 0.036000000000000004, 0.028, 0.032, 0.06, 0.052000000000000005, 0.06, 0.04, 0.056, 0.048, 0.044, 0.032, 0.036000000000000004, 0.044, 0.048, 0.056, 0.06, 0.04, 0.052000000000000005, 0.036000000000000004, 0.06, 0.056, 0.052000000000000005, 0.04, 0.044, 0.048, 0.052000000000000005, 0.06, 0.056, 0.048, 0.044, 0.048, 0.056, 0.052000000000000005, 0.06, 0.06, 0.052000000000000005, 0.056, 0.06, 0.056, 0.06])

z=np.array([95.04597652659395, 93.07169300791817, 86.41091378436298, 78.34438186919142, 84.28293560208068, 90.99430316168865, 82.05075271093197, 70.81956500179922, 76.09555746842769, 88.80946213542661, 73.74247054741866, 63.814701759030804, 79.70713086816829, 68.4804576360916, 86.50492808734144, 61.411971344204396, 71.27993747341829, 57.30367846300854, 66.04015177478145, 84.07501743344253, 77.24301883685469, 74.65362436130224, 51.26423750067391, 58.91207005961288, 54.86318852178682, 63.49153397778519, 68.6991473720035, 81.50849542102088, 48.8094605989559, 56.31211751844223, 60.83162919739374, 45.67567310972991, 78.7945025104922, 71.92736246929788, 52.33202775655146, 65.99398045254483, 75.9227956237361, 40.51568403157141, 43.22761997937239, 63.15759412126584, 58.05355658264885, 69.05560979875929, 46.272987182375566, 53.60665663794348, 49.70877412288789, 38.09431844582127, 35.76611318237437, 66.02941761913569, 72.88105942465431, 50.794014788290504, 55.15315977444494, 60.1826102793514, 43.65339424937394, 40.70815913994665, 46.99112474144888, 33.39135870389347, 57.06201132927449, 69.65537451933291, 35.6145715150264, 62.83835882162572, 31.40773179439253, 44.17796418876675, 52.12445158267965, 40.952566664906996, 38.11850878026559, 47.86983942422426, 33.07706500252916, 30.968759803924296, 59.472616777191334, 48.96396982344986, 27.42232365576576, 29.095469972744016, 66.23369927283454, 53.78907408633386, 38.16920129740417, 41.26718319757395, 35.460618219452655, 44.83267388998538, 30.486209186684196, 45.66877097031951, 26.7492079741212, 25.1879876184327, 50.357833903749956, 23.793264961588868, 28.503632233000594, 41.68143865195456, 55.92411681399547, 62.602040414153436, 32.737080106531906, 38.262204180250805, 35.307079275214086, 20.504965629265598, 26.001941824443026, 22.934787566648367, 35.16414842828048, 24.375915837974958, 38.417647482512585, 52.183223475400425, 46.764236521960356, 27.847695627594547, 21.651951344041745, 42.23745078550662, 58.7486635658336, 32.370568277953886, 29.953599826849384, 23.472939828370624, 43.0064416381895, 29.365624602515823, 48.245841005914286, 25.17053808625563, 31.979981680064885, 18.467992104439183, 35.045344071560066, 54.66218711883382, 20.669937446692995, 19.505408609505, 21.983371919011866, 38.67214321103867, 17.539733461223655, 27.117574924924078, 31.572812873998643, 22.466032542732094, 16.443245776120413, 24.2409420001134, 17.365732951566233, 28.718698301383473, 18.405920693287136, 19.584790929537345, 20.927274270297637, 44.10975175851463, 15.621134390166244, 26.303364418342934, 14.884854891742494, 50.33532348260853, 39.08801072397429, 34.978370361105966, 25.396357763334883, 13.093794646214183, 15.245360559256401, 28.01403749316034, 17.192124683229846, 21.339430775662887, 16.155565837989112, 19.74917859564828, 18.380058183613784, 31.168656484960362, 23.199805388379076, 35.017572733654454, 14.44199394670105, 39.77998854987883, 13.729070264143143, 11.346911104669699, 14.826597675743553, 24.39190718008288, 18.434180461079755, 22.034810233530056, 15.851362438599907, 13.161307980429406, 30.815540283692425, 11.880002954924821, 20.077222490194877, 17.041644543286573, 12.480819689160308, 13.937187381696818, 27.26500078493244, 12.51094881156381, 16.966980870415316, 23.303152376399595, 14.370711153030173, 11.135186711010434, 10.090487273914302, 11.77391829747407, 10.578674928530958, 9.66079764755596, 13.367708069288115, 15.555350065743474, 20.740782967906497, 18.667665977595888, 10.277243048965051, 9.693623758996056, 17.113566938669496, 8.055866920180963, 8.384375391031437, 10.962604505357024, 11.773924988908062, 15.34327076939705, 13.913536319438865, 9.192626639560688, 8.760402036693474, 12.743127231680926, 7.732751057134466, 7.36675841687418, 8.165298800642773, 8.680802847878777, 6.787933025877766, 9.300489076468914, 10.05339503288019, 6.557384688690587, 10.978653802485539, 12.131123230834657, 7.055085859022233, 6.22731794094746, 5.937938719418917, 5.699224545702991, 5.500815523085859, 5.195664664070231, 5.334932485979189, 7.0171502171500615, 8.249070447101744, 6.580911352886527, 7.561330476433264, 4.367976775112049, 4.143264099643755, 4.241684382135572, 4.066603365531463, 4.530455892542467, 4.739999538254734, 5.370823105713089, 5.012619143814073, 4.0071751320157984, 3.0409176976014267, 3.037921536588448, 3.1622049587954795, 3.034404773151192, 3.0607972205754965, 3.098909471280704, 3.407285944994312, 3.260238193353411, 2.228405125954436, 2.2403142547782524, 2.301784702795703, 2.3435558143108883, 2.237381252011389, 2.2663466711203877, 2.27735590501212, 1.9930746922320377, 1.9480623234072603, 1.9115118902381407, 1.9071495409410206, 1.8831262520810794, 1.8877684267325927, 2.093097490680202, 2.0718660504293087, 2.0726202431163654, 2.141268771079559, 2.2287157638764166, 3.1800800140087624, 2.8008846853966536, 2.960115226464081, 2.6865687087736654, 3.970923041282829, 4.704638756418261, 4.292188345854714, 6.093648447344786, 6.750181957450197, 9.269311560401611])

ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z,cmap ='viridis')
plt.show()
plt.contourf(np.reshape(x,(int(len(x)**0.5),int(len(x)**0.5))),np.reshape(y,(int(len(x)**0.5),int(len(x)**0.5))),np.reshape(x,(int(len(x)**0.5),int(len(x)**0.5))))
plt.show()
```

The 3D plot looks quite nice, but the 2D filled contour is all jagged, and I'm not entirely sure why. The 2D contour plot also appears to be flipped from the 3D counterpart. I suspect this is due to me setting up the `contourf` improperly, but I cannot see the problem.

[image: 3D Plot]

[image: 2D Plot]

Comment: To plot 3 1d arrays onto a 2d, use `plt.tricontourf(x, y, z)`

Comment: [`.tricountourf` onto `.plot_trisurf`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXJqo.png) and [`tricontourf`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO9XX.png) separately.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [Make a contour plot by using three 1D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65172931/7758804)

Comment: Thank you guys, this is exactly what i was looking for. If one of you would like to put it as an answer I can accept it

Comment: The answer is from the other question, so I've closed it as a duplicate.